# Unable to Re-Create Cumulative Series, After Calculating Incremental But Making No Changes. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, series, cumulative-sum

I am not able to calculate incremental change between values in a series, and then re-sum and create a series that is identical to the initial series. Why? This should be possible; I am making no changes at all to the data here.

In my real application, I am working with weather station data, which outputs cumulative precipitation in the gage; I would like to set incremental values that are in error (e.g. during service visits) to 0, and output a new cumulative timeseries. In trouble-shooting this, I noticed that I am introducing changes to the timeseries simply by calculating incremental change values, and re-summing, which I thought should give me identical values. What am I missing here?

```
#Original values in cumulative series
vals=pd.Series(np.random.randn(250000).cumsum())

#Calculate incremental change
incremental_vals=vals-vals.shift(1) #calculate incremental changes

#Calculate cumulative sum of incremental values
new_cumulative=incremental_vals.cumsum()
new_cumulative[0]=vals[0] #set first value of new cumulative series to equal iniitial value; NAN introduced

#Check if new series equals original
vals.equals(new_cumulative)
```

The two series are not equal. Plotting gives further insight:
[image]

How can I create an incremental change series and re-sum to cumulative **without introducing any changes?** If this is not possible, I would very much appreciate an explanation why.

Comment: You miss the first value when re-calculate the cumsum. You need `new_cumulative[1:] = new_cumulative[1:] + new_cumulative[0]`

Comment: @Ian - thanks for the pointer. Was able to fix with: `new_cumulative = new_cumulative + vals[0]
new_cumulative[0]=vals[0]`. Your comment was adding `new_cumulative[0] ` instead of `vals[0]`; if you add that as an answer, I will accept it. Thanks!

Comment: For others who may read this - having NANs in your series also creates differences; it is better to fill them before differencing as well.

Comment: yeah, I meant to add that line to the last, which is after you assign vals[0] to new_cumulative[0].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering for myself so I can refer to this later:

```
#Original values in cumulative series
vals=pd.Series(np.random.randn(250000).cumsum())

#Calculate incremental change
incremental_vals=vals-vals.shift(1) #calculate incremental changes

#Calculate cumulative sum of incremental values
new_cumulative=incremental_vals.cumsum()
new_cumulative = new_cumulative + vals[0] 
new_cumulative[0]=vals[0] #set first value of new cumulative series to equaliniitial value; NAN introduced
```